# IP release and renew return the same IP on a new LAN with different IP scheme

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp

Something strange I've encountered for the first time. Windows 7 PC was movied from one LAN to another and still kept getting the same IP address from DHCP as it did at old LAN location. For example,

Old LAN IP(192.168.**1**.0/24 network): 192.168.1.34

New LAN IP(192.168.**2**.0/24 network): 192.168.1.34

Releasing/renewing DHCP didn't help. Computer can still use internet but has no access to LAN resources such as printers. Setting IP to static works, but it should work off DHCP.

Disabling adapter and restarting computer and restarting dhcp services doesn't fix this.

Have you ever encountered this? Why would computer get old IP assigned by new DHCP with new IP address network?

Comment: This is probably caused by a poor quality, malfunctioning, or improperly configured or implemented DHCP server, I have seen this before. What is handing out your DHCP offers and have you cleared the leases?

Comment: If you can surf the internet with the "wrong" ip address, then that tells me 192.168.1.x is a valid address on the "new" LAN, which doesn't' seem right (based on the info you've provided), and could show that perhaps there is a reachable DHCP server on the "new" LAN's 192.168.1.x subnet. Which DHCP server does `IPconfig /all` show as the DHCP server it contacted?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Default Gateway and DHCP Server IPs are still pointing to old LAN IPs... That's strange because in adapter settings it's set to automatic not static addresses. Why does it keep getting outdated info?

Comment: @acejavelin DHCP is handled by a router and I'll check if leases are cleared.

Comment: @acejavelin Just checked router, and everything seems fine(no mention of 192.168.1.X network anywhere), but I didn't find DHCP leases page.

Comment: @user573533 reboot the router, if it still gets an IP in the wrong range, turn off the router and see if you still get ip address, this is sounding like a rogue dhcp server could be in play

Comment: @acejavelin No, the router is DHCP server itself. Router has static IP configured for itself. It's just that one computer that keeps getting old IP assigned.